# using variables in tailwind / react

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have problem, that tailwind not interpretet variables in class.

Bellow my code:

```
// header
const HeaderComponent = (props) => {
  const { color } = props;
  return (
    <div className={`border-2 p-3 border-${color} hover:bg-${color}`}>
      <div>{color}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

{color} is working in div, but not is className line.

Props look like:

```
const SectionComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div className="container max-w-screen-lg pt-3 pb-3 mx-auto">
      <HeaderComponent color="blue-800" />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: See [dynamic class names](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names)

Comment: @Spikatrix normall variables is not working?

Comment: No it won't work as mentioned in the link

Answer (score 0):

As Tailwind scan your code to look for complete class names, you can't build these names dynamically.
A possible solution is to use the style attribute:

```
<div style={{borderColor: color}} .../>
```

Another is to pass the entire class names as props:

```
<HeaderComponent borderColor="border-blue-800" backgroundColor="hover:bg-blue-800" />
...
<div className={`border-2 p-3 ${borderColor} ${backgroundColor}`}>
```